# Bulkheading strategies for Akka actors

Tags: java, asynchronous, akka, blocking, future

I have a scenario where an important actor needs to make a call to a slow (15 - 20 **seconds**) remote system:

```
// Non-actor code equivalent
public Result makeSlowNetworkCall(Request request) {
    Result result = slowServiceClient.soooooSlow(request);      // Could be up to 15 - 20 SECONDS (mehhhh)
    return result;
}
```

The Akka equivalent to this is *currently* looking like:

```
// Groovy
class SlowServiceActor extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof CallSlowService) {
            Request request = (message as CallSlowService).request
            Result result = makeSlowNetworkCall(request)
            // ...now do something with result, some 15 seconds later
        }
    }

    Result makeSlowNetworkCall(Request request) {
        slowServiceClient.soooooSlow(request)
    }
}
```

Obviously this is blocking and bad, bad, bad. After reading [this excellent article on handling non-blocking DB calls](http://noisycode.com/blog/2014/07/27/akka-and-jdbc-to-services/), my main takeaway is that there are essentially two "*bulkheading*" strategies I can employ:

- Place all `SlowServiceActor` instances in their own dispatcher, to isolate their latency/blocking-ness from other actors/threads that don't interact directly with the Slow Service; and
- Invoke the Slow Service via `Futures` for true "*asynchronicity*"

So my best attempt thus far is:

```
// In application.conf:
slowServiceDispatcher {
    ...config here
}

class CallSlowService implements Callable<Result> {
    @Override
    Result call() throws Exception {
        slowServiceClient.soooooSlow(request)
    }
}

// Created using the "slowServiceDispatcher"
class SlowServiceActor extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof CallSlowService) {
            Request request = (message as CallSlowService).request
            Future<Result> callSlowServiceFuture = Futures.future(new CallSlowService())

            Result result = ???

            // ...now do something with result, some 15 seconds later
        }
    }
}
```

But as you can see, I have a few problems:

- I think I am misunderstanding the `Futures.future(...)` API; I don't think that's meant for constructing new `Futures`
- How do I actually obtain the `result` in a non-blocking fashion?
- And finally: am I missing anything here? Any strategies I'm not utilizing/leveraging that I should be?

Comment: I dont particularly understand akka, but for a general event based system, shouldnt there be a different handler for processing results from the soo slow service?

Comment: Thanks @RajatGarg (+1) - *yes*, but that handler will need a way of not just calling back into the actor system, but to that particular actor in that particular execution context. Without knowing Akka, it will be tough for you to see why this makes the typical callback/handler solution infeasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you kind of have two options here: you listen to a `Future` being completed or you do something with the result:

If you want to listen, you can use some callback like

```
final ExecutionContext ec = system.dispatcher();

future.onSuccess(new OnSuccess<String>() {
  public void onSuccess(String result) {
    if ("bar" == result) {
      //Do something if it resulted in "bar"
    } else {
      //Do something if it was some other String
    }
  }
}, ec);
```

The other way would be to `map` the future's result. So you have the something like:

```
callSlowServiceFuture.map(new Mapper<ReturnType1, ReturnType2>() {
  public ReturnType2 apply(ReturnType1 s) {
    // do something with 's'
  }
}, ec);
```

This way you say "... the moment I get a result from the service call, please manipulate it as described in apply ..."